# Что нужно установить, чтобы выполнялась команда node в терминале  в ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js

В windows скачал установщик, поставить и все работает, а на ubuntu я установил nodejs и после попытки вызвать команду node в терминале, получаю сообщение -

> Приложение 'node' может быть найдено в
> следующих пакетах:
> node 
> nodejs-legacy
> Попробуйте: sudo apt-get
> install <выбранный пакет>

убрал звездочки из цитаты, а то они её ломали.

Что конкретно нужно ставить? Нужно для angular и ему подобных.

Comment: Вы сильно удивитесь, но нужно установить ноду. Более того, умная убунта сама подсказала даже как. Скорее всего это будет `sudo apt-get install nodejs`.

А вот к angular это не имеет никакого отношения. Абсолютно. Ему (angular'у) абсолютно побоку, кто будет по http отдавать статику и json.

Comment: Про angular может и не прав.. но дело не в этом. Для меня Ваши слова не так же удивительны, как и предложенный Вами вариант. Судя по ответу Вы даже не поняли, что я спросил.. Хотя и моя вина в этом тоже есть - форум цитату в одну строчку слил, а я только сейчас увидел. Сейчас попробую поправить и буду ждать поправленного ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы таки не поверите...

> Приложение 'node' может быть найдено в следующих пакетах: **node**
>
> Попробуйте: sudo apt-get install **node**

Comment: Посмотрите что я дописал в вопросе и комментарии выше.

Comment: А вы посмотрите что я написал в ответе.

Comment: Ответ выше говорит о том, что либо Вы не увидели двух пунктов из которых нужно выбрать, либо подумали, что я не знаю, как установить...  
Вопрос - "что выбрать, а или б", ответ - "попробуйте а". И наверное если не заработает, то следующий ответ будет б?)

Comment: @shatal, мамой поклясться? тельник на груди порвать?

Comment: @shatal, legacy в данном контексте трактуется как "устаревшая, но рабочая версия".  Вам не просто так ответ написали.

Comment: Вот теперь ответ полный! Спасибо и сорри, если был настойчив. Но у меня не работает) Я пытаюсь echo вернуть из js файла и не работает...

Comment: @shatal echo из js файла ? ну напишите перед этим сначала

    function echo(text) {
       console.log(text);
    }

:)

Comment: занырните хотя бы сюда http://habrahabr.ru/post/146983/

Comment: @eicto: так меня этот node замучил, что перепутал. При чем перепутал не сказав здесь, а на самом деле echo написал))) Но все равно не работает...